# Can I use "First, ... Secondly, ... Finally, ... " like this ?

Tags: expressions

I would like to say :

> First, I would like ...
>
> Secondly, I am ...
>
> Finally , I think ...

is it correct ? and what we call this kind of structure ?
is there alternatives ?

Comment: Recommended reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/18961/3281.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words first, secondly, finally are called linking words. They introduce the sequence of events in a story, narration, etc.

There are plenty of alternatives:

Following, Later, Once, Next, Subsequently, Thereafter, First, Firstly, Initially, To begin, Next, Second, Secondly Then, Third, Thirdly, Finally, Last, Lastly.

As for your sentences, they are correct.